# jQuery event when something happens to the element

Tags: jquery

Is there any even which is common for all actions (eg. click, focus etc)? Let's say I need to bind a behaviour in jQuery to an element and execute it if ANYTHING happens to it (I don't want to recognise whether it was a click, focus or anything else. I've been searching for these events for a while but cannot spot anything like this.

Comment: There is not. Different elements can fire different events, so you have to manually enumerate all the events that you want to listen to. Just space-separate the events when binding, e.g. `$('input').on('click change input focus')`

Comment: Ok, its good enough for me to know that there is no a such thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `change` to check for changes on elements
(Deselect the input to update the value)

```js
var times = 0;
$("input").change(function() {
  times++;
  $(".times").text(times);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text"/>
<span>text has been changed: <span class="times">0</span> times</span>
```

Comment: Yes, change event works for me, but I thought there will be something more general. Anyway it solves my problem, so thank you

Comment: @Morales If you work with data instead of elements you can check for changes on the data values instead, then you can capture everyting. But if you dont need that just use what ever function works :)